# When calling the MediaWiki-API I only get '+\' as an csrf-token

Tags: php, mediawiki

I can edit with the simple token '+\' but with this simple token I can edit only as an unregistered IP, not as an registered user. Can someone help me?

My PHP code:

```
$parameters = array('action' => 'query', 'meta' => 'tokens', 'format' => 'json');
$options = array(
   'http' => array(
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'content' => http_build_query($parameters),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($wiki, false, $context);
echo "$result";
```

Comment: I would suggest using cURL for this type of things. Makes it cleaner and handles all the protocol stuff for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be logged in to get a real CSRF token. For details on how to log in, see:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login

Note that staying logged in will require that you store cookies across requests. This will be difficult with `file_get_contents()`; using cURL with a cookie jar is recommended.

Comment: I tried without cURL but it doesn't work:  'http' => array(
 'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
  Set-Cookie: $cookieprefix = $sessionid;\r\n
   dewikiUserName = $lgname;\r\n
   dewikiToken = $token",
 'method'  => 'POST',
 'content' => http_build_query($parameters),
    ),

Comment: @mischa004 That definitely won't work — the client header is supposed to be `Cookie`, not `Set-Cookie`.

Answer (score 2):

To get a [login token](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tokens) use the `type=login` parameter. Example:

```sh
curl 'https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json&type=login'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turns out i forgot to set the cookies again after logging in.

1. GET login token
2. SET COOKIES
3. POST login (using the login token)
4. SET COOKIES
5. GET csrftoken

This would be the code using axios

```
  const api = axios.create({ baseURL: `${YOUR_MEDIAWIKI_HOST}/w/api.php` });

  const loginTokenResponse = await api.get('', {
    params: {
      action: 'query',
      meta: 'tokens',
      type: 'login',
      format: 'json'
    }
  });
  const { logintoken } = loginTokenResponse.data.query.tokens;
  setCookies(loginTokenResponse);

  const loginResponse = await api.post(
    '',
    {
      action: 'login',
      lgname: YOUR_USERNAME,
      lgpassword: YOUR_PASSWORD,
      lgtoken: logintoken,
      format: 'json'
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }
  );
  setCookies(loginResponse);

  const csrfResponse = await api.get('', {
    params: {
      action: 'query',
      meta: 'tokens',
      format: 'json'
    }
  });
  const { csrftoken } = csrfResponse.data.query.tokens;
```

setCookies:

```
function extractCookies(setCookieHeaders: any) {
  const cookies = setCookieHeaders.reduce((acc: any, header: any) => {
    const cookieKeyValue = header.split(';')[0];
    const [key, value] = cookieKeyValue.split('=');
    acc[key.trim()] = value.trim();
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return cookies;
}
function setCookies(response: any) {
  const setCookieHeaders = response.headers['set-cookie'];
  const cookies = extractCookies(setCookieHeaders);
  const cookieHeader = Object.entries(cookies)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
    .join('; ');
  // We set a cookie header for upcoming requests
  api.defaults.headers.Cookie = cookieHeader;
}
```